# Code working on Simulator, but not on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I am stumped by this: I've tested the filter function of my app in the iPhone Simulator 4.3 and 5.0 and everything works, but on the iPhone the predicate gets me the wrong results. (I suspect it has something to do with the regex, but I don't see an error.)

```
if (!selectionDidChange)
    return;
[matches release];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"meta LIKE[c] %@",
                          UniversalKeyword];
NSPredicate *regional = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"regional == NIL OR regional == NO OR "
                         @"(regional == YES AND title.%K != NIL)", CurrentLanguage];
NSPredicate *exclusive = (exclusiveUpgrade ? [NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES] :
                          [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"exclusive == NIL OR exclusive == NO"]);
NSMutableArray *predicates = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5] autorelease];
for (int i = 0; i < L(keywords); i++)
{
    int selection = [D(A(keywords, i), @"selection") intValue];
    if (selection >= 0)
        A_ADD(predicates, ([NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"meta MATCHES[c] %@",
                            S(S(@".*\\b", D(A(D(A(keywords, i), @"values"), selection), @"name")), @"\\b.*")]));
}
NSPredicate *compound = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates];
[predicates removeAllObjects];
[predicates addObject:predicate];
[predicates addObject:compound];
predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:A_NEW(regional, exclusive,
            [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates])];
matches = [[entries filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] retain];
selectionDidChange = NO;
```

**For clarification:**

- `entries` and `keywords` are arrays of dictionaries, although `keywords` is a bit more complex. Important is that each dictionary in `entries` contains a string named `meta` that can look something like this: "A, B, C, D". And if the user searches for "C", the regex should match. There are other criteria that don't seem to be the problem, since I checked the compiled predicate and it looks fine.
- I should mention, the first part of the predicate (`meta LIKE[c] %@`) gives me the expected result on the iPhone as well.
- I have some used convenience macros here: `A_ADD = addObject:`, `D = objectForKey:`, `A = objectAtIndex:`, `A_NEW = arrayWithObjects:`, `L = count` and `S = stringByAppendingString:`. (Yeah, I'm lazy :D )

What am I overlooking here?

Comment: Some items in the simulator are not case-sensitive. i.e. "@2x" and "@2X" would both display a retina image in the simulator, but not the device. Ensure that the capitalization you're passing around is what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that's good to know. However, I looked closer at the NSLog output and saw that the app on my device pulled data from an out-dated cache file; I should've deleted the app first and the predicate would've worked fine. It can be that easy sometimes ...

Comment: Glad you got it. Either provide the answer or mark this puppy closed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the key points in case anybody else has a similar problem:

1. There are no functional differences between `NSPredicate` on the iPhone and the corresponding implementation on the iOS Simulator.
2. If your app behaves differently on the actual device than on the Simulator, double-check file names and other strings for capitalization, like *jmstone* said.
3. If the problem persists, remove the app both from the Simulator and from the device. Xcode has many automatic behaviors, but it doesn't clean up anything on the Simulator or the device.